# Why postinst not running after installation?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh, post-install

I create a .deb package for my app and postinst script is not running after installing .
this is my postinst script under the the path of DEBIAN/myapp.postinst

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "start postinst packing"
#fix app process permission 
sudo chown root:root /opt/MyApp/myapp
sudo chmod 4755 /opt/MyApp/myapp
echo "finish set permissions"
exit 0
```

Comment: Add verbosity when you install your package (are you doing with `dpkg` so that you have more control). In any case, you should read a lot more documentation and knowing better distribution and security implications. Why `sudo`? (it is wrong!, it is supposed you are already superuser). I'm scaried about permission too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the *DEBIAN/* directory create a file named postinst and copy your script into it, or change the name of *myapp.postinst* to *postinst* and you're ready to go

Comment: yes this was the issue . thank you .